# How can the upper bound of an array be 0 while it has been allocated?

Tags: arrays, segmentation-fault, fortran, indexoutofboundsexception

I am facing a segmentation fault so I tried to compile the code with `-fcheck=all` and after executing, I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
At line 237 of file app_management_test.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '1' of dimension 1 of array 'free_workers_list' above upper bound of 0
```

I don't understand how can the upper bound be 0.
Here is a part of the code where I used the array `free_workers_list`.

```
 !Thread Application Master (numero 1)
       if (num_thread==1) then
          do ff=5,20 ! 16 tasks 
             if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true.) then
                tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff)
                tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
             end if
          end do
       end if

   
   if ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then          
      do ff=1,nthreads-2
         if (num_thread==ff+1) then

            tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
            free_workers_list(ff)=1 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! line 237 (error)
            call  tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var)
            tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_INACTIVE
            free_workers_list(ff)=0
            s=size(tasks_ready_master)
            call erase(1,s,tasks_ready_master)

         end if
      end do
```

And here is a part of the subroutine:

```
subroutine management(tasklist_GRAD,var)
    INTEGER ::ff,l
    type(tcb)::self
    type(variables)::var
    integer::s
    !OpenMP variables
    integer::num_thread,nthreads
    integer:: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS    
    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master
    integer::STATUS
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::free_workers_list !liste contenant les nums des threads workers 
    !Variables pour gestion des threads 
    INTEGER(KIND=omp_lock_kind), SAVE :: lock

    CALL omp_init_lock (lock)

    !=======================================================================================================================================================
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,nthreads,ff) &
    !$OMP SHARED(tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master,free_workers_list)
    num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() ! le rang du thread 
    nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() ! le nombre de threads

    if (nthreads<3) then
       print *, 'This program is going to exit.'
       call EXIT(STATUS)
    end if

    !Thread Master (number 0)
    if (num_thread==0) then

       allocate(free_workers_list(nthreads-2)) ! liste des threads workers 

       do ff=1,nthreads-2
          free_workers_list(ff)=0 ! 2,3,..,nombre de threads-2
       end do
    end if


   

       !Thread Application Master (number 1)
       if (num_thread==1) then
          do ff=1,3 ! 3 tâches
             if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true. ) then ! Si tâche attribuée 
                tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff) ! égalité de pointeurs 
                tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
             end if
          end do
       end if




       !Threads Workers (number diff than 0 and 1) 
       if (nthreads==5) then  ! 5 threads ==> 3 workers 
          if ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then
             
             do ff=1,nthreads-2
                if (num_thread==ff+1) then

                   tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
                   free_workers_list(ff)=1 !!!!!!!!! error 
                   call  tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var)
                   tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_INACTIVE
                   free_workers_list(ff)=0
                   s=size(tasks_ready_master)
                   call erase(1,s,tasks_ready_master)
                end if                
             end do
             
          end if
end subroutine management
```

For `EXIT` : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXIT.html

For `erase` : it's a subroutine I implemented to remove an element from an array.

Compiler: `gfortran`

Comment: If `nthreads` is equal to 2 then why wouldn't the extent be 0?  Please show more detail on how you run the program. (See [mre].)

Comment: @francescalus there is a check beforehand which explicitly prohibits the special case of `nthreads < 3`. Something else must be off here.

Comment: @jack Yes, exactly. I don't understand how the upper bound is 0 while I allocate at minimum one element (nthreads minimal value is 3.)

Comment: @francescalus `nthreads` is greater than 3.

Comment: @jack, if you mean `call EXIT(STATUS)` then there's no indication what that subroutine does.

Comment: @hakim we still need to see more code. What else are you doing after the allocation in the parallel block? You might be accessing the array even though it is not allocated (`num_thread=0` might not be the first thread to perform in the parallel region).

Comment: @jack Done. I posted the whole subroutine.

Comment: @francescalus `EXIT` causes immediate termination of the program with status. If status is omitted it returns the canonical success for the system. All Fortran I/O units are closed. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXIT.html

Comment: @hakim You have a better chance of help here if you boil down the code to just a few lines which shows the error. See the MWE link above from francescalus.

Comment: If you are using gfortran then you should say that in the question. This is important information when using a non-standard intrinsic procedure (and without a [mre] we can't even tell whether you are using that intrinsic procedure).

Comment: @francescalus Yes, I am using gfortran. I edited my post. Is it okay right now ?

Comment: @jack `free_workers_list` is declared as a `shared` variable so I think that when the thread num 0 (Master) allocates the array, the modification should be seen also by the other threads.

Comment: @hakim You have a race condition. There is no synchronisation to ensure the array is allocated by thread 0 before it is used by threads 2, 3, and 4. Whether this is the cause of your problem I can't tell at the moment.